# jQuery: unbind event that was bound with live()

Tags: jquery, click, bind, live, die

I have an unordered list with five list items, each with a link inside of it:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

The links have a click function bound to them with `live()`:

```
$("a").live("click", function(){
    ...
});
```

Inside of this function is a `get` request that retrieves some information.

So, when any of these links are clicked, I want to prevent clicks on any of the *other* links from doing anything until the `get` is complete. I thought I could do this by unbinding the click event with `die()`:

```
$("a").live("click", function(){
    $("a").not(this).die("click");
    ...
});
```

But this doesn't work. I don't get any errors - it just doesn't prevent the click event. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try $("a").die(); to remove all the event handlers on $("a") that were installed using live or just $("a").die("click"); for what you want

Comment: `live()` is deprecated, use `on()` and `off()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to use `live` and `die` on a different set of elements.  In order to function correctly you must apply `live` and `die` to the same selector / set of elements.

```
$('a').live('click', function () { ... });
$('a').die(); // Ok! 
$('a').each(function () {
  $(this).die();  // Doesn't work.  
});
```

It sounds like you want to only temporarily disable this though until a specific operation completes.  If so then you can do this with a handle / dontHandle switch.

```
(function() {
  var doHandle = true;
  $('a').live('click', function() {
    if (!doHandle) {
      return;
    }

    // Don't handle any events until the 'get' is complete
    doHandle = false;
    doGet(this, function() { 
      // Call back for when the get is complete.  Start handling again
      doHandle = true; 
    });
})();
```